How to migrate from mbox to maildir++ layout in Dovecot?
I followed the official Dovecot guide for configuring the mailbox to allow child folders and all the folders I created before changing the configuration disappeared. In ~/mail I still have the old folders and I tried to move them around to mimic the structure of the folders I created after changing the configuration but I cannot get it to work.
I don't care about recovering the folders themselves, what I want to do is get those emails back, so I can sort them into new folders.
The configuration in /etc/dovecot/:
#---/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf---

mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u:LAYOUT=maildir++:INDEX=~/mail/index:CONTROL=~/mail/control

I can change the configuration back, move everything to inbox, then add the maildir++ layout and sort from inbox, but I'm hoping for a better solution.
Turns out I was wrong, after changing the configuration back to what it was now all my mails are gone except for inbox. Please advise.
